# Test in PowerShell code if a folder is a junction point?

Tags: powershell, ntfs, junction

How can I test in PowerShell code if a folder is a junction point?

Comment: Are you going to mark a post as the right answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at this blog:
https://web.archive.org/web/20190422210654/https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/viewing-junctions-with-dir/

the way to do it is to copy the built in file system formatting file, modify it so that junctions are indicated, then load it with *Update-FormatData*:

From the Blog:

> The file system formatting rules are
>   in `$pshome\FileSystem.Format.ps1xml`. I
>   copied this, then in the element
>   `[ViewDefinitions –> View –> TableControl –> TableRowEntries –> TableRowEntry –> TableColumnItems –> TableColumnItem]`
>   I changed the content
>   of *PropertyName* with value of 'Mode'
>   to the following:
>
> ```
> <ScriptBlock> 
>    "$($_.Mode)$(if($_.Attributes -band [IO.FileAttributes]::ReparsePoint)
> {'J'})" </ScriptBlock>
> ```
>
> This does a bitwise AND on the
>   DirectoryInfo object Attributes
>   property (`$_.Attributes`) against the
>   .Net `System.IO.FileAttributes.ReparsePoint`
>   enum value. If the result is not zero,
>   it displays a ‘J’ next to the other
>   file mode attributes. Next, load the
>   new formatting file like this:
>
> ```
>  PS> Update-FormatData -PrependPath myFilesystem.format.ps1xml
> ```
>
> The *PrependPath* parameter ensures that
>   the new formatting file is loaded
>   before the built-in formatting files.
>
> Directory alink has a ‘J’ in the mode
>   column, seems to work!
>
> It's in the Mode column J for
>   Junction.

Answer (score 9):

Since at least PowerShell v5.0, there is better support for links (or as MS calls them: Reparse Points)

[improved Item cmdlets - **LinkType** property](https://web.archive.org/web/20180409044159/https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/wmf/5.0/feedback_symbolic)

Linked article is under WMF 5.0 category, which might mean that the method was available since PS v5.0.
These features were included in standard Get-Item, Get-ChildItem, so there are no additional steps required. It can be used on any current PS.

LinkType is a String property on an Object, returned by Get-Item and Get-ChildItem,
it can have one of the following four values: '', 'Junction', 'SymbolicLink', 'HardLink'.

To answer OP's question, you can check if a folder is a junction point using:

```
if ((Get-Item -Path $Target -Force).LinkType -eq "Junction") { }
```

To check if a file/folder is a "ReparsePoint", of any kind (Junction, SymbolicLink or HardLink):

```
if ((Get-Item -Path $Target -Force).LinkType) { }
```

LinkType value on ordinary file/folder is an empty String, which when used as *if* condition in PS resolves to False

Get-ChildItem can be used to list all Junction folders:

```
(Get-ChildItem -Path $Target -Force) | Where-Object { $_.LinkType -eq "Junction" }
```

Note that value 'SymbolicLink' is the same for both file or folder, so to list only Symbolic links to folders:

```
(Get-ChildItem -Path $Target -Directory -Force) | Where-Object { $_.LinkType -eq "SymbolicLink" }
```

Cmdlet Get-ChildItem (alias: dir, ls, gci) now shows ReparsePoint attribute, as `l` in Mode column, without any extension. But it will not show 'HardLink' and shows `l` for both Junction and SymbolicLink:

```
> Get-ChildItem -Path $Target -Force


    Directory: C:\Users


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                          
----                -------------         ------ ----                          
d--hsl       2018-04-12     01:45                All Users                     
d-rh--       2018-05-09     06:12                Default                       
d--hsl       2018-04-12     01:45                Default User                  
d-----       2018-06-24     03:05                Papo                          
d-r---       2018-07-27     07:12                Public
```

- LinkType does not work on folders with special permissions inside \Users and \Users\, even though Get-ChildItem as seen above does work and shows `l` on them.
- Remove-Item has issues. It can't remove Junction, and if Forced, will remove original contents with it. This is said to be fixed in future version PS v6

---

Using these improved, or today's standard Cmdlets, has some advantages over previous methods, described in older answers here.

- It does differentiate between Junction and Symbolic Link
  If OP wanted to test if folder is a Junction, checking by Attribute property would result in false positive for folder Symbolic Link.
- detects Hard Link.
- LinkType is [String] as opposed to Attributes property, which is [FileAttributes] type and needs .ToString() or a use of -band

Comment: It's not just "Users" that `LinkType` doesn't work on. For example, on my computer running W10 with PS 5.1, LinkType is null for both "C:\Documents and Settings" and "C:\ProgramData\Desktop", whereas `dir /aL` (Command Prompt, not PowerShell) indicates they are both junction points. `LinkType` just does not appear to be reliable for reparse points.

Comment: Very comprehensive answer that should be ranked higher for anyone using a modern PowerShell release.

Answer (score 7):

If (Get-Item *Test Folder*).Attributes.ToString().Contains("ReparsePoint"){*Code*}

Comment: This is the only solution that does not rely on changing PowerShell config files or using third party extensions. An alternative version is:
if ((Get-Item Test Folder).Attributes -match [System.IO.FileAttributes]::ReparsePoint){Code}

Comment: The OP asked for a programmatic solution, and this is just that.

Comment: That's a test for any type of reparse points and will be true for other non-junction reparse points such as NTFS symbolic links and volume mount points. See [papo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51563174/1640661) for how to differentiate between the varous types of reparse points in recent releases of PowerShell.

Answer (score 1):

FYI, if you happen to be running [PowerShell Community Extensions](http://pscx.codeplex.com), this info is available as output (and as a note property) on output of Get-ChildItem:

```
21> gci .\Roaming\Microsoft\eHome


    Directory: Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\Users...


Mode           LastWriteTime       Length Name
----           -------------       ------ ----
d----     2/15/2010 12:18 AM        <DIR> DvdCoverCache
d----      8/9/2009  1:10 AM    <SYMLINK> DvdInfoCache [\...
d----      8/8/2009 11:51 PM        <DIR> DvdInfoCache.orig
d----    10/22/2009  7:12 PM        <DIR> mcl_images
```

However for programmatic access I would access the info via the Attributes property as the other poster suggests.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the PowerShell Community Extensions which I would recommend if you are working with junctions you can do the following to determine if a folder is a junction or not:

```
Import-Module pscx
if ((Get-Item *test_folder*).ReparsePoint){
    Write-Host "YES"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$TargetAttributes = (Get-Item -Path $Target -Force).Attributes.ToString()
if ($TargetAttributes -match "ReparsePoint") {
    if ($TargetAttributes -match "Archive") {
        Write-Output ("Link to a file.")
    } else {
        Write-Output ("Link to a folder.")
    }
} else {
    Write-Output ("Normal File or Folder.")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Example for exclude Junction from listing (or "-match", for exclude all another):

```
(Get-ChildItem -Force | where {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $true -And $_.Attributes -notmatch "Reparse"})
```