# Get-ChildItem -force reports "Access Denied" on My Documents folder and other junction points

Tags: powershell, acl, access-denied

I have a script that I wrote that replaces files.  I pass params to it for the name of the file, and the base location to search from.  The worker lines are:

```
$SubLocations = Get-ChildItem -Path $Startlocation -Recurse -include $Filename -Force  | 
                Where { $_.FullName.ToUpper().contains($Filter.ToUpper())}
```

I set $Startlocation to "C:\Users", however, I am getting access denied when trying to recurse through other users folders.  I'm full admin on the machine, and I have already tried running powershell as admin.  I can access all the files via Windows explorer with no issue.  Any idea?

```
Get-ChildItem : Access to the path 'C:\Users\jepa227\Documents\My Music' is denied.
At C:\Users\krla226\Google Drive\Documents\PowerShell\Replace-File.ps1:35 char:46
+ $SubLocations = Get-ChildItem <<<<  -Path $Startlocation -Recurse -    include $Filename -Force | 
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (C:\Users\jepa227\Documents\My     Music:String) [Get-ChildItem], Una 
   uthorizedAccessException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId :  DirUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

**UPDATE**

While I was unable to get it working via GCI, I was able to use WMI to solve my problem.  For those interested:

```
$SubLocations = Get-WmiObject -Class cim_datafile -Filter "fileName = '$filename' AND Extension = '$extension'" | 
                            Where { $_.Name.ToUpper().contains($Filter.ToUpper()) }
```

Comment: Is UAC enabled? I tried on a non-UAC Windows 7 box with multiple users and didn't encounter an Access Denied when trying to access other users' directories. Also, what OS/Powershell version are you using?

Comment: UAC is disabled, but I'm also in a domain.  I can't remember if that will make a difference or not.  Running 7 pro 64-bit and Powershell 2

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was able to reproduce this on a Windows 7 machine with the following command logged in as an admin user named "admin", running powershell with elevated privileges, and UAC disabled:

```
get-childitem "c:\users\Admin\my documents"
```

and

```
cd "c:\users\admin\my documents"
get-childitem
```

Based on the article [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-security/access-denied-to-the-my-documents-and-settings/915eecc8-6a07-4d6a-8ca5-468ee51e9484?auth=1), it looks like My Documents, My Music, etc., are defined as junction points for backwards-compatibility with pre-Vista software. Powershell doesn't natively do well with junction points. It seems like there are a couple options here:

1) Remove the -force from the Get-ChildItem command. This is likely your best bet.

```
get-childitem c:\users -recurse
```

works without error and skips junction points and system directories like AppData.

<sup>Editor's note: Omitting `-Force` does solve the immediate problem, but invariably skips *all hidden* items, not just the hidden junction points that cause the access-denied errors.</sup>

2) If you absolutely need to use the `-Force` for some reason, you could programmatically recurse each subdirectory, skipping junction points. [This article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2311105/test-in-powershell-code-if-a-folder-is-a-junction-point) describes the mechanism to identify junction points. A skeleton of this in a .ps1 script file might look like:

```
Param( [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$startLocation )

$errorActionPreference = "Stop"

function ProcessDirectory( $dir )
{
  Write-Host ("Working on " + $dir.FullName)

  # Work on the files in this folder here
  $filesToProcess = ( gci | where { ($_.PsIsContainer -eq 0) } ) # and file matches the requested pattern
  # process files

  $subdirs = gci $dir.FullName -force | where {($_.Attributes -band [IO.FileAttributes]::ReparsePoint) -eq 0 -and ($_.PsIsContainer -eq 1) -and (![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($_.FullName))}

  foreach( $subdir in $subdirs )
  {
      # Write-Host( $subdir.Name + ", " + $subdir.FullName )
     if ( $subdir -ne $null )
     {
       ProcessDirectory -dir $subdir
     }
  }
}

$dirs = get-childitem $startLocation -force
$dirs | foreach { ProcessDirectory -dir $_ }
```

Comment: This would not work for my situation, as I was trying to replace items within other users Appdata.  Without -Force, it wouldn't even attempt to find their Appdata folder.

Comment: Removing -force doesn't help and it has nothing to do with junction points. I has the same issue with temp files.

Comment: @Suncatcher: `-Force` comes into play, because these system-defined junction points also have the _hidden_ attribute. Without `-Force`, PowerShell doesn't see hidden items.

Answer (score 6):

[mcating's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24258018/45375) explains the problem well.

The quick fix he suggests is to omit `-Force`, which works, because PowerShell *ignores* hidden items unless `-Force` is used, and these system-defined junction points do have the `Hidden` attribute (alongside the `ReparsePoint` and `System` attributes).

**If you do need `-Force` in order to process hidden items in general and only want to ignore these system-defined junction points**, you can use `Get-ChildItem`'s `-Attributes` parameter as follows:

```
Get-ChildItem -Force -Recurse -Attributes !Hidden, !System, !ReparsePoint
```

The `-Attributes` value *excludes* all items that have *all* of the following attributes set: `Hidden`, `System`, `ReparsePoint`, which is true of all system-defined junction points.
While it is technically possible to create your own junction points (or symbolic links) with these attributes, this is unlikely to occur in practice.

Answer (score 1):

PS C:\PSScripts>

```
Get-ChildItem -Attributes !Hidden, !System, !ResparsePoint -Recurse -Force   "C:\Users\" 
Get-ChildItem : Cannot bind parameter 'Attributes'. Cannot convert value "System.Object[]" to type "System.Management.Automation.FlagsExpression`1[System.IO.FileAttributes]". Error: "Unable to match the identifier name ResparsePoint to a valid enumerator name. Specify 
one of the following enumerator names and try again:
ReadOnly, Hidden, System, Directory, Archive, Device, Normal, Temporary, SparseFile, ReparsePoint, Compressed, Offline, NotContentIndexed, Encrypted, IntegrityStream, NoScrubData"
At line:1 char:27
+ Get-ChildItem -Attributes !Hidden, !System, !ResparsePoint -Recurse - ...
+                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ChildItem], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

Have you ever tried using values like !Hidden, etc? Didn't think so. It doesn't accept these values.

Comment: You spelled ReparsePoint wrong.