# How to recursively search a directory for all files including hidden files in hidden directories, with PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, search

To recursively search for a hidden file, I am using:

```
gci -Path C:\ -Filter part_of_filename* -Recurse -Force | where { $_.Attributes -match "Hidden"}
```

The output shows me many errors exactly like this (depending on the path):

> Get-ChildItem : Access to the path 'C:\Documents and Settings' is
>   denied. At
>   C:\Users\USERNAME\Documents\powershell\searchdisk.ps1:10
>   char:5
>   +  gci <<<<  -Path C:\ -Filter part_of_filename* -Recurse -Force | where { $_.Attributes -match "Hidden"}
>       + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (C:\Documents and Settings:String) [Get-ChildItem], UnauthorizedAccessException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand

I need a PowerShell command that recursively searches ANY directory including hidden directories and shows me all files including hidden files of the name part_of_filename* (for this example)

I ran the command using PowerShell ISE as Administrator. It won't search inside directories like

> C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\WMI\RtBackup

Comment: This would definately need to run with Elevated rights

Comment: The problem is that Documents and settings is not a directory, but a junction point. Some NTFS-trick to make programs believe the directory is still there, while it really is a shortcut to Users. Here's a SO question about the topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2311105/test-in-powershell-code-if-a-folder-is-a-junction-point

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're doing it right. Just run it in an elevated console and remove the filter. If you don't care about permission errors, append `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\ -Filter lush* -Recurse -Force `
              -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue


Directory: C:\

Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
-arhs        25.09.2013     12:16       1208 lush.asx
```

`lush.asx` has the *ReadOnly*, *Hidden* and *System* attributes.

You may also want to pipe to `| select Name, Length, Directory` to get rid of that unfortunate `Directory: C:\` line. There's also a `DirectoryName` if you want the full path without the filename.